# How do I set up a periodic function on iPhone to run in the Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, timed

I am writing an iPhone app that among other things, is supposed to automatically sync with a server every minute. I can make the app sync, but I am having trouble figuring out how to keep track of the time in the background (while the app is foremost) and sync automatically.

I have never done anything complex with multi-threaded programming, so I am still fairly new to it.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this? Or at least a good place to start?

Comment: That sounds like a battery killer. Every _minute_?. You certainly won't be able to run that in the background (ie when the user is using a different app), do you mean that or just in the background when your app is foremost?

Comment: Only when my app is foremost. Sorry I guess I shouldn't use the word "background." Also it doesn't necessarily sync every minute. For the purposes of what I'm doing I only need to know when a minute has passed.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are trying to sync app every one minute, then that will make the app slower and drain out the battery. What you can do, you can check if some configuration is changed only then sync the app.
2. For this stuff you can probably use background thread to perform the task when some configuration changes.
3. You need to consider the scenario when app quits, special handling for that in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

The method you would use is `-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *) application`

You would put all code in there that you will do once the application enters the background.

If you are having something checking the server every minute I dont believe this is possible on the iPhone but there is a way to do Push Messages.

Here is a tutorial on Push messages http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Here is the devolper library as well http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html

You can use push notifications to alert the user something new is in the app and once they return to the app then it checks and grabs whatever from the server.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To set up the repeating sync call, you'll want to use a repeating NSTimer instance. You can find all the sample code you'll need to set up a NSTimer in Apple's [Using Timers Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE).

You'll want to probably use a dispatch_queue using dispatch_async in order to keep it from blocking the UI. Or if you're using the ASIHTTPRequest network library, it will automatically use NSOperationQueues for network operations. If not, you'll have to do that yourself.

I highly recommend watching some of the Grand Central Dispatch and Blocks WWDC session videos from 2010/2011 (I assume you're a registered developer). This topic is bigger than one question, and you'll need to understand the subtleties of using GCD. One thing to note though: if your syncing process ends with the app UI updating, you must do that via the main thread. You'll need to call your UI update method via a dispatch_async using the main_queue. The session videos will explain that.

Finally, as others have mentioned, hitting the server every minute will potentially cause power drain. Even if you don't "sync", the simple act of going out to the network means the iPhone has to power up the 3G radio each time. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: If you want to avoid mixing runloops and dispatch queues, use a dispatch_source_t set to DISPATCH_SOURCE_TIMER and you can do all of this in one step.